# Gradle: Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes

Tags: gradle

According to the [documentation](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/aspectj.gradle), I've tried to use aspectj plugin.

This is the message I get when I build my project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jesudi/projects/gradle-vscode/build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'security'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'aspectj.gradle']
   > Could not create task ':compileAspect'.
      > Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.
```

This is my script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.apache.meecrowave:meecrowave-gradle-plugin:1.2.6"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.9.2'
}

apply plugin: 'aspectj.gradle'
apply plugin: "org.apache.microwave.microwave"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.apache.meecrowave:meecrowave-core:1.2.6")
    compile("org.apache.meecrowave:meecrowave-specs-api:1.2.6")
}

meecrowave {
    httpPort = 9090
    // most of the meecrowave core configuration
}
```

This is the `gradle -version` output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-20-generic amd64
```

Answer (score 34):

In Gradle 5.x, this property has been renamed to `classesDirs` from `classesDir`.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput:classesDirs)

Answer (score 12):

Possible your plugin is not a root of problem but the version of Gradle is.
First time I had the same error in libgdx game (android studio).
In build.gradle(desktop) file "classDir was renamed to classesDirs and it helped.

```
from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)
```

Answer (score 6):

The `classesDir` property was deprecated in gradle 4.x, and removed in gradle 5.x (see the [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html)).

The plugin has apparently not been maintained.

Comment: Which plugin are your referring to?

Comment: The one the question and the error message are about.

Comment: I can see that the script has 2 plugins applied:
`aspectj.gradle` and `org.apache.microwave.microwave`. Hence I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error message, not with this plugin but even with the HelloWorld app created by Grails (3.2.9). In my case, I already used sdkman to set my current Gradle to 3.5 instead of 5, but the problem persists. It turned out that the "grails" cli (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3.2.x/grails-shell/src/main/groovy/org/grails/cli/gradle/GradleUtil.groovy) uses the default  sdkman version for Gradle (which is different from the "current" version).
From Grails 3.3.X, one can set "gradleWrapperVersion=3.5" in gradle.properties instead, or use GRAILS_GRADLE_HOME environment variable as before.